# Form Follows Function in Programming?

Tags: programming-languages, design, language-agnostic

Does the saying, "**form follows function**" hold true in programming or language-design? Why or why not?

Comment: Why would you think so? Where else does it hold true, that you are comparing it to?

Comment: This would be a very good area to study. All kinds of things to look at. Function of the app (LOB vs Games vs shrinked wrapped) and what forms of programming are used. The "function" of methods/classes/modules and the design choices made (probably would tend towards the design patterns we all know but maybe not). etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does, in that the way a program is organized will be determined by the functionality required.

With that being said, "form follows function" says nothing about the quality of the form.  Only that the requirements of the functionality play a major part of the form of the design.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, it's [Convay's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law):

> Any organization that designs a system (defined broadly) will produce a design whose structure is a copy of the organization's communication structure.

System design (Form) is influenced by the organization's communication structure, which, in turn, is adapted to certain business activities (Function).

Answer (score 1):

In FORTRAN, form follows subroutine. In Objective-C, form follows method.

Comment: Someone boo this man.